# Website migrated from IIS server to Linux

Tags: php

I changed server from IIS to Linux. In form submissions I was using `if ($user)` which didn't work in linux.

For Linux I changed it to `if ($_POST["user"])`. This means it is using the value passed in the form.

But if I keep on changing files like this, it will take lot of time. I want these to be worked as if `$user` only like it was on IIS. I am using WHM so maybe there is a setting for the same?

Comment: It's not an OS issue. It's a PHP config issue. You don't have register_globals turned on (which is a good thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the server to enable [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). This setting is considered dangerous (as it is too easy to write insecure code using it) and was deprecated and then removed from PHP.

You may have to downgrade PHP in order to enable it.

Bring your code up to date. Register Globals was considered bad practice when I used PHP over a decade ago.

Comment: Thanks a ton, will re-write the code again.